# How can one learn to write sophisticated SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure it's a correct place to ask so please forgive me if it's not. I want to be able to write sophisticated SQL queries. What is the best way to learn to write sophisticated SQL queries? Maybe there's a list of example tasks somewhere over internet? Please note that I'm not a novice in MySQL, so please do not advise reading big books like "Mysql. Complete guide". An article or a list of example tasks will be great!

Comment: by term sophisticated, you mean what?

Comment: Everything is sophisticated before it became simple..you need to check at what levels you are finding complexity while writing queries..try to implement sub-queries/joins/performance check etc at various dummy databases kept over the internet..although i too agree with the point that something still missing over the internet for intermediate to advance lvl of query writing

Comment: You might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306682/tips-on-becoming-an-sql-guru

Comment: Read the questions on stackoverflow (and dba.stackexchange) and try to answer them, or understand the accepted answers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name out of the many ways ur suggestion is really the best ( how could i forget that im doing the same for my learning )  +1

Comment: @swapnesh: what does `ur suggestion` mean?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name following stack and dba.stackexchange as most of the people only referencing to books..however the questionnaire is looking for some real stuff to understand it better and i believe that following the questions at stack/dba would really going to help any one a lot if interested to learn

Comment: Btw: don't constrain yourself on MySQL. It lacks so many modern SQL features....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for SQL Challanges, there are several sites that pose problems, have a go at finding solutions and see what others do.

Try http://beyondrelational.com/ for starters.

Answer (score 0):

[Joe Celko - SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123820227) is an excellent book.

Answer (score 0):

Create PHP/MySQL website. Make it "do" things. First, simple things. Then get inspired. Ask, "is it possibly to do ..." something. It is, so now do the research and figure out how.

There are all sorts of "sophisticated" queries. Which ones you learn depends on what you are trying to DO. So, first try to DO something, then learn the queries.

E.g., perhaps you want to display hierarchical information, like a tree menu. How would you stored that in a database, and what kind of queries would show you things like:

Items with n parents.
Items with n children.
Items that are their own grandpa.

Now you have a concrete problem to solve, a goal to spur you to learn actual queries. I don't see any other way to learn these things than to have a real question to motivate you.

Answer (score 0):

sql reference is a nice book

you can find this  here
http://books.google.co.in/books?id=gfjKrrj0FicC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

[Simply SQL](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/sql1/) from Sitepoint is a really easy to understand book on SQL that explains clearly how to do advanced querys, also I think you can download the first few chapters free